# Rails link_to/form_for/etc. with array for path and URL query parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that I can do this to build a link with URL parameters:

```
<%= link_to 'Widget from Something',
            admin_widget_path(@widget, from: :something) %>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this while also passing an array as the 2nd argument instead of the `_path` helper?

For example, what would I add to this to get the `?from=something` added to the URL like in the first example?

```
<%= link_to 'Widget from Something', [:admin, @widget] %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that by **adding a hash** of the URL params **as the last element** of the `link_to` array:

```
link_to 'Widget from Something', [:admin, @widget, { from: :something }]
```

The proof for this lies in the Rails sources: `link_to` calls [`url_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb#L98), which, with an array argument passed in, **performs an extraction of the options from the array** by calling the [`extract_options!` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options.rb) on the array. This method is an ActiveSupport extension of the Array class with the following doc string:

> Extracts options from a set of arguments. Removes and returns the last element in the array if it's a hash, otherwise returns a blank hash.

Comment: Perfect. I'm surprised that I couldn't find this anywhere in the docs about linking.